# Ubuntu is not adding SD card to /dev/

Tags: nvidia, mount, sd-card

I have a [NVIDIA TX2](https://developer.nvidia.com/embedded/buy/jetson-tx2), and the SD card is automatically mounted when the UI is visible. The problem is when I log in to the TX2 without GUI (Graphic User Interface), via SSH it doesn't read SD cards.

I watched `/dev/` path, and I can't see the SD card device. So I think for some reason the SD card is not read when I disable the GUI. I tried using `lsblk`and `fdisk -l` but the device is not shown.

Comment: Mine is mount in `/media` directory

Comment: That is not the problem.

This is the mounted SD:
`mmcblk1p1  179:17   0  29.3G  0 part /media/nvidia/0403-0201`

This is how an unmounted SD looks like:
`mmcblk1p1  179:17   0  29.3G  0 part`

Comment: Some SD card readers need to be polled to discover media insertion and removal. It's possible that this process is only enabled in the configuration of the run level for the graphical session. There should be a way to poll manually but I don't know it.

Comment: Gui is scanning devices for you. If no Gui, try this. Run dmesg, them insert SD card, then dmesg again. If it shows messages about new device, then mount the old fashioned way. If dmesg shows nothing, it means you really do need the Gui to scan devices.